# Why does changing the base value of a css property disable hover activation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element which changes opacity when hovered. At some point during my javascript, I change the base opacity value of this element. However, even if I change the property back to its original value, the `:hover` selector no longer triggers. 
 This is how the code works without changing the base value:

```css
#hover-div:hover{
      opacity:1;
    }
#hover-div{
  background:red;
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
  <div id = 'hover-div'>
    Hover on me.
  </div>
```

As expected, the div becomes fully opaque when hovered. However, if I now introduce two lines of javascript which set and then reset the opacity value, the hover effect no longer triggers:

```js
document.getElementById('hover-div').style.opacity = '1';
document.getElementById('hover-div').style.opacity = '0.7';
```

```css
#hover-div:hover{
      opacity:1;
    }
#hover-div{
  background:red;
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'hover-div'>
    Hover on me.
  </div>
```

How can I change the base value using js while still keeping the effects of the css hover? (preferably using vanilla js/css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), inline styles will always override CSS selectors. What you are looking for is to actually remove the opacity style using `removeProperty('opacity')` so that the **.hover-div** selector applies:

```js
document.getElementById('hover-div').style.opacity = '1';
document.getElementById('hover-div').style.removeProperty('opacity');
```

```css
#hover-div:hover{
  opacity:1;
}

#hover-div{
  background:red;
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
<div id='hover-div'>
    Hover on me.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the Javascript sets the styles inline, inline styles take precedence over external stylesheet